# Second-order Cellular Automaton definition

Tags: terminology, definition, cellular-automata

What does second-order term mean in a Cellular Automaton?

I read on [second-order cellular automaton (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cellular_automaton) that a second-order has two time-states, but does the definition of an order mean the number of time-variables that the function $f$ maps onto?

If we have *two* cells at time $t-1$ instead of *three*, and one cell at $t-2$, this is not a second-order cellular automaton? if yes, why is this so? It says all second order are reversible.

I ask because there are tons of ways to construct an Cellular Automaton, and therefore it is nice to know which terminology to use when describing the automaton.

Answer (score 1):

Second order cellular automaton relay also on the layer at $t-2$ for pattern computation.

As "neighborhood" in Second order term is the cell at the step $t -2$ respect the present state of the cell in $t -1$, and on those information will derive the final outcome of the same cell at $t+0$.